# Python variable scope giving undefined for defined variable

Tags: python, scope, global-variables, nameerror

Why is this variable undefined? Using `global` fixes it (need to set `global serviceFile` too), but I thought you only need to specify `global` if you are modifying global variables.

```
  File "./test_menu.py", line 18, in generateTemplateList
    serviceFilePath = templateDirectory + '/' + directory + '/' + serviceFile
NameError: name 'templateDirectory' is not defined
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

# Constants
templateDirectory = './.templates'
serviceFile = 'service.yml'

menu = []
templateDirectoryFolders = next(os.walk(templateDirectory))[1]

def generateTemplateList(templateDirectoryFolders):
  templateListDirectories = []
  for directory in templateDirectoryFolders:
    serviceFilePath = templateDirectory + '/' + directory + '/' + serviceFile
    if os.path.exists(serviceFilePath):
      templateListDirectories.append(directory)

  return templateListDirectories

templatesList = generateTemplateList(templateDirectoryFolders)
for directory in templatesList:
  menu.append([directory, { "ticked": False }])
```

I'm getting similar errors with functions too, like:

```
def foo():
  return "hi"

def bar():
  print(foo())

bar()
```

```
  File "./test.py", line 6, in bar
    print(foo())
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with second code snippet. See this
https://onlinegdb.com/H18K0E2tL

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's a bug in Python when using exec: https://bugs.python.org/issue4831

Answer (score 0):

check the indentation.

```
def foo():
    return "hi"

def bar():
    print(foo())

bar()
```

you have use tab for indentation not space

Comment: Still same error. I'm using vscode, but I'm not sure why it would care if I'm using spaces or tabs if the indentation is the same (and I'm just using one or the other). I copied your answer exactly.

Answer (score 0):

this is the identation correct

```
import os

# Constants
templateDirectory = './.templates'
serviceFile = 'service.yml'

menu = []
templateDirectoryFolders = next(os.walk(templateDirectory))[1]

def generateTemplateList(templateDirectoryFolders):
    templateListDirectories = []
    for directory in templateDirectoryFolders:
        serviceFilePath = templateDirectory + '/' + directory + '/' + serviceFile
        if os.path.exists(serviceFilePath):
            templateListDirectories.append(directory)

    return templateListDirectories

templatesList = generateTemplateList(templateDirectoryFolders)
for directory in templatesList:
    menu.append([directory, { "ticked": False }])
```

Comment: Please use the edit option on your post instead of posting twice.

Comment: @Scratte Were you talking to me? I didn't write this answer